# How can I overlay Sentinal 2 data with shapefiles in R?

Tags: r, geospatial, raster, satellite-image

I need to extract Sentinal 2 data for NDVI for specific study sites. I used RGIS tools and followed the reference manual https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RGISTools/RGISTools.pdf . I was able to obtain and plot the time series for NDVI.

Now I have to do the same procedure for my study area. I have a shapefile for my area which is accessible here, https://gis.utah.gov/data/boundaries/zip-codes/. It looks like that the shapefile needs to be converted into raster or sf type object before using it. I used `st_as_sf` to convert shapefile to sf but I receive the following error in `senSearch` function,

*Error in if (as.integer(json$feed$`opensearch:totalResults`) > 0) { : 
  argument is of length zero*

It is my first time working with such data, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you try to search using the extent argument. This argument only accepts spatial objects projected as lonlat projections. You can use the region argument with any spatial obj (sp, sf, or raster).

Here you have an example with your region:

```
library(RGISTools)
library(rgdal)
shp<-readOGR("ZipCodes_shp/ZipCodes")
plot(shp)

senres<-senSearch(startDate = as.Date("2018210", "%Y%j"),
                  endDate = as.Date("2018215", "%Y%j"),
                  platform = "Sentinel-2",
                  region = shp,
                  product = "S2MSI1C",
                  username="user",
                  password="pass")
```